# How to change the content of a page with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've been able to pull pages from wikipedia and serve them from localhost with the code below.  I want to be able to change the logo also.  I attempted to do that with the .replace() function but it's not working.

```js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.url)
  var options = {
    host: 'en.wikipedia.org',
    port: 80,
    path: req.url,
  };

  var req = http.get(options, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      chunk.replace("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png","http://www.sotmclub.com/images/logo.png");
      res.write(chunk, 'utf8');
    });
    res.writeHead(response.statusCode, response.headers);
  });

}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: You could use jsdom + jQuery http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs

Comment: How about putting the chunks in a buffer first. Then do str-replace??

Comment: Aren't the chunks already coming in a buffer?  How would I put them in buffers and then write them out to the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in javascript are immutable. All `chunk.replace` is doing is returning a new string. You have to instead do `chunk = chunk.replace(...)`.